# Python Recursively Search for Filename (sys.argv) > Print to output file

Tags: python, recursion

I am attempting to write my first python script that will (1) recursively search the entire file system for a specific file; (2) print to screen the location of the file; and, (3) save the file contents location to a text file in the root directory.

I have scoured stackoverflow and am still not succeeding... please help! Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). It will do exactly what you want, and there is an example in the standard python reference

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

[effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/librarybook-index.htm) is also a good reference to review sometimes, about half way down this post on [`os.path` module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/os-path.htm) is a section called *Traversing a File System* that also covers `os.walk`

Answer (score 0):

To quote Adam Savage, "Well, THERE'S your problem!"

You should be scouring the [python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/) for the answer to this, not StackOverflow.  As a hint, you'll want to read about [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).